# Initialize the function In the form of Variable in php

Tags: php, function, variables

How can i set the function as a variable in php
Similar to list function

```
example: list($x,$y)=array(1,2); // this is okey ,but...
```

How do I create such a structure?

Comment: can you please more explain

Comment: `How do I create such a structure?`->what structure? Can you please explain your question a bit more

Comment: I want to set the function to be similar to the variable.
Similar to the list function. fun(a,b)=array(1,2)
but 
But I can not make that this functional
.I want to know how the list function is designed. That i can not

Comment: I want to know how the list function is designed. That i can not.
I have trouble with this syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about variable function that if a variable name has parentheses appended to it, PHP will look for a function with the same name as whatever the variable evaluates to, and will attempt to execute it. Among other things, this can be used to implement callbacks, function tables, and so forth.

Here is the little example from PHP manual [Variable Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

```
function foo() {
    echo "In foo()<br />\n";
}

function bar($arg = '')
{
    echo "In bar(); argument was '$arg'.<br />\n";
}

// This is a wrapper function around echo
function echoit($string)
{
    echo $string;
}

$func = 'foo';
$func();        // This calls foo()

$func = 'bar';
$func('test');  // This calls bar()

$func = 'echoit';
$func('test');  // This calls echoit()
```

and the other scenario is [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), also known as closures, allow the creation of functions which have no specified name. They are most useful as the value of callback parameters, but they have many other uses.

```
$greet = function($name)
{
    printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
};

$greet('World');
$greet('PHP');
```

Comment: I want to know how the list function is designed. That i can not. I have trouble with this syntax

Comment: list() is not a user build function. It is in-built language construct of PHP. whenever you assign an array to to list function then php internally assign all array values to list function variables. Its the internal part of PHP.
lets take example of your own user made function myOwnFunction($a,$b)=array('1','2');  this will generate fatal error. that means you can not do like that. Only that is the functionality provided by php for list().

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$my_array = array("Dog","Cat","Horse");

list($a, $b, $c) = $my_array;
echo "I have several animals, a $a, a $b and a $c.";
?>
```

The list() function is used to assign values to a list of variables. Like array(), this is not really a function, but a language construct. list() is used to assign a list of variables in one operation.

Comment: I want to know how the list function is designed. That i can not. I have trouble with this syntax